# RestClient Parsing URI with Space on Request Path

Tags: ruby, parsing, rest, rest-client

I'm currently working on a code where I'm requesting a URL with space on request path:

```
http://example.com/path1/path2/some details.detail?keyword=key word
```

I'm using [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) gem.

```
url = http://example.com/path1/path2/some details.detail?keyword=key word
RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: url)
```

But it throws an error:

```
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://example.com/path1/path2/some details.detail?keyword=key word
```

The documentation suggests to parse and normalize the URL first:

```
parsed_url = Addressable::URI.parse(url).normalize.to_str
# parsed_url is now: http://example.com/path1/path2/some%20details.detail?keyword=key%20word    
RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: parsed_url)
```

But the error still exists.

```
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://example.com/path1/path2/some details.detail?keyword=key%20word
```

It looks like it cannot parse the `/some details.detail` part of the url.

Does anyone encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try `URI.encode`:

```
$ irb
2.0.0-p247 :001 > require "uri"
 => true 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > URI.encode("http://example.com/path1/path2/some details.detail?keyword=key word")
 => "http://example.com/path1/path2/some%20details.detail?keyword=key%20word" 
2.0.0-p247 :003 >
```

Comment: OP's problem is not with the encoding, but that he forgot to use the new variable `parsed_url` when checking what worked . . .

Comment: You sure?  He used `parsed_url`, and the error after "But the error still exists" looks like it only encoded the query string.

Comment: Not 100% certain, but I just followed OP's steps and everything worked fine. Look carefully at the last error message and you will see the URI is not the same as in the previous step.

Comment: Ahh, I see he commented "parsed_url is now..." and that looks right...  No clue! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `rest-client` 1.6.7 and `addressable` 2.3.5, on Ruby 2.0.0, this is an irb session trying to replicate your fault:

```
:001 > require 'rest-client'
 => true

:002 > require "addressable/uri"
 => true

:003 > url = 'http://example.com/path1/path2/some details.detail?keyword=key word'
 => "http://example.com/path1/path2/some details.detail?keyword=key word"

:004 > parsed_url = Addressable::URI.parse(url).normalize.to_str
 => "http://example.com/path1/path2/some%20details.detail?keyword=key%20word"

:005 > RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: parsed_url)
RestClient::ResourceNotFound: 404 Resource Not Found: <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>
```

It seems to work ok according to your own solution. As far as I can tell you either missed out repeating a step whilst investigating the problem (try again, from the start, just in case), or perhaps it is a bug in an older version of one of the two gems you are using - in which case you could fix it by installing latest versions.

Comment: Thank you Neil for your comment. The above code works. However, when trying to implement this to the actual URL: `http://muse.aucklandmuseum.com/databases/Muscat/MP 98.detail?keywords=Shell Oil New Zealand Hauraki Gulf` it breaks. Any ideas?

Comment: Look carefully at the URL it is rejecting. You are getting a re-direct, also with a space in, and `rest-client` is trying to auto-follow and *then* not handling it . . . that seems tougher. If I go straight to the re-direct URL I get a 404 from the server instead, so the connection works.

Comment: I created a [pull request](https://github.com/benedictaluan/rest-client/commit/e93d50fee9be75f42e381ba1bfccf97300888308) to the rest-client gem about the issue. For now, I did a monkey path to fix this issue.